# Android GPS distance ZERO, when walking back to start position

Tags: android, gps

I have an android application which calculate distance from GPS while walking. When I start application and go straight it gives the correct distance but when I back to the starting point it distance decreases. Finally it shows 0, when I reach to the original position.

So, my question is how can I calculate distance perfectly of my every step.

Here is my activity:

```
public class Gps extends Activity {
TextView display;
Button start;
boolean doubleclick = false;
AnimationDrawable AppNameAnimation;
private boolean enabled;
double currentLon = 0;
double currentLat = 0;
double lastLon = 0;
double lastLat = 0;
double distance;
Location loc;
Animation animRotate;
TextView startStop;


LocationManager lm;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    startStop = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_rotate);

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!doubleclick) {
                lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                enabled = lm
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (!enabled) {
                    Intent inte = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(inte);
                } else {
                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                            Loclist);
                    Log.e("successss", "111111111111");
                }
            } else {
                lm.removeUpdates(Loclist);
                startStop.setText("Start");
                v.clearAnimation();
                doubleclick = false;
                Intent in = new Intent(Gps.this, NextActivity.class);
                // in.putExtra("distance", display.toString());
                startActivity(in);
                finish();
            }

        }
    });
}

LocationListener Loclist = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("successss", "2222222222222");
        // start location manager
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist);
        // Get last location
        if(!doubleclick){
        Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.e("successss", "33333333333333333");
        if (loc == null) {
            display.setText("No GPS location found");
        } else {
            Log.e("successss", "444444444444");
            // set Current latitude and longitude
            currentLon = loc.getLongitude();
            currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
            Log.e("Location", "currentLat:" + currentLat);

        }
        Log.e("successss", "5555555555555");
        // Set the last latitude and longitude
        startStop.setText("Stop");
        lastLat = currentLat;
        lastLon = currentLon;
        doubleclick = true;
        }
        Log.e("successss", "66666666666");
        Log.e("Location", "lastLat:" + lastLat);
        Log.e("Location", "currentLat:" + currentLat);
        //Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);
        // Request new location
        //lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Loclist);

        // Get new location
        Location loc2 = lm.getLastKnownLocation(lm.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // get the current lat and long
        currentLat = loc2.getLatitude();
        currentLon = loc2.getLongitude();

        Location locationA = new Location("point A");
        locationA.setLatitude(lastLat);
        locationA.setLongitude(lastLon);

        Location locationB = new Location("point B");
        locationB.setLatitude(currentLat);
        locationB.setLongitude(currentLon);
        if (lastLat != 0 || lastLon != 0) {
            double distanceMeters = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
            double distanceKm = distanceMeters / 1000f;

            display.setText(String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            Constant.distance = (String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
            start.startAnimation(animRotate);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

};
}
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, I edited my question. Please help me. It is very important to me. Thank you. Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be mistaken (I haven't really dug into your code) but could it be as simple as this:

It sounds like you're continuously calculating the distance from some point x = (0, 0). Of course, when you return towards x, the distance from it will decrease.

Simple solution:

- Separate the distance calculated for each "step" from the total distance
- For every time you calculate the distance, reset the starting point (move X to your current position), and add the new distance to a total.

Comment: Thank you brother. Can you please show me how can I do that. I tried with this but some where I cause mistake.Please.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
 double distanceMeters = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
 double distanceKm = distanceMeters / 1000f;
 display.setText(String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
 Constant.distance = (String.format("%.2f Km", distanceKm));
 start.startAnimation(animRotate);
```

The `Location.distanceTo(Location)` method is calculating the distance in `meters`. `%.2f` will only show 2 digits after the comma and cuts the last digit. Because `1 meter / 1000f = 0.001 km`. That's why you will never see the 3rd digit in your TextView. The result for distances < 10 meters will be shown as 0.00.

Comment: I walked around 0.14km, when I back it was decreasing like 0.13,0.12,.....0.01

Comment: @MohammadRajob What's your expected result?

Comment: When I click a button, it will start to calculate distance while I am walking. The output will be 0.00km initially, 0.01km,then 0.02km....., When I will back it will increasing until I click the button again.